# Size of my object changing

Tags: jquery

How the length of activites can be different in the same object?

Chrome JS console :

```
Jour {date: "2014-12-01", numero: "0", activites: Array[1], isWeekend: false, commentary: undefined…}
activites: Array[2] :
  0: Voyage
  1: Affaire
  length: 2
commentary: undefined
date: "2014-12-01"
isWeekend: false
numero: "0"
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question not a link to an image of it.

Comment: this is an image of chrome console, not any "code" here

Comment: show the `activities` values which is hidden in your codes and image.

Comment: this is a list of other objects here : activites: Array[2] : 
0: Voyage
1: Affaire
length: 2

Comment: Where does that object come from? If `numero` does not match the count of `activities`, something must have gone wrong when building the object. Also, you may not need the `numero`, as you could get the number of `activities` by using `activities.length`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! `numero` is the number on the week, not the length of activites :) But when I print a simple `console.log(jour.activites.length);` i got 1 instead of 2, and when I print the object, I see 2 objects in  `activites` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the little information icon near the object output in console. The collapsed output displays state of the object in the moment of console.log() call. But the expanded output represents state of object at the moment of expanding it in console.

Try e.g. in console

```
var o = {a:[1,2]}
// undefined
o
// Object {a: Array[2]}
o.a.push(3)
// now expand the object above
```

Comment: I would consider reverting to original question to show actual information icon from console.